# "It had been set previously."

Tags: adverbs

Where is the proper placement for the adverb "previously" (are any of these incorrect usage?)? Do each connote a subtly different meaning?

- It had been set previously.
- It had been previously set.
- It had previously been set.
- It previously had been set.

Edit: Thanks for the comments. It would be helpful if you guys can give some scenarios where one would make sense over another.

Comment: This depends very largely on context, and on where it makes sense to put the emphasis. I can see myself favouring each one in different circumstances (if "It had been previously set to 'high' " say is allowed.

Comment: Yep, they're all valid (and generally interchangeable), but which one is preferred depends on context.

Comment: And *Previously, it had been set.*

Answer (score 1):

Previously is an adverb of time relationship, and as such, it can be placed at the beginning of a sentence, at the end or in the middle (after the verb 'to be', after the auxiliary verb and before any other verbs).

This way,

> 1. It had been set previously (end of sentence)
> 2. Previously, it had been set (beginning of sentence)
> 3. It had been previously set (mid-sentence, after auxiliary verb 'had', verb 'to be' and before verb 'set')
> 4. It had previously been set (mid-sentence, in between auxiliary verb 'had' and verb 'to be' (which is also correct, as we have a complex verbal form) and before verb 'set')
>
>    and
> 5. It previously had been set (can be considered at beginning of sentence, verb-wise)

are all correct, and the difference between them is mostly in formality and their usage depends on context.